# Storing a value returned from function to a variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

```
dbo.UDF_CONVERSION (7.68,1,null,null,25,5)
```

has the formula

```
(7.68/1000.00)/1.0026
```

and returns the answer as `0.007680000`

```
DECLARE @A nVARCHAR(1000),@i float
SELECT @A= dbo.UDF_CONVERSION (7.68,1,null,null,25,5)
SELECT @A='SELECT '+@A
exec @i=sp_executesql @A
select @i
```

When i execute the above the value I am getting is `0`
I want `0.007680000` so that I could use the value for further processing.

Comment: What type of data returned by the function UDF_CONVERSION  ?

Comment: Why are you storing the result of a float devision in a varchar variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't feel good writing this, but you can achieve what you want with a temporary table.

```
DECLARE @A nVARCHAR(1000),@i float, @retVal int
--drop table #tblReturnedVal
create table #tblReturnedVal (val float)
SELECT @A= dbo.UDF_CONVERSION (7.68,1,null,null,25,5)
SELECT @A='insert into #tblReturnedVal SELECT '+@A
exec @retVal = sp_executesql @A
select top 1 @i = val from #tblReturnedVal
select @i
select @retVal -- 0 = sp_executesql ran successfully, 
                -- otherwise something went wrong
```

Edit: you should definitely do it how @Mate suggested

Comment: Tanx it works but is there any other way , even i am ready to do this in a stored procedure instead of function

Comment: Maybe you need add DROP TABLE #tblReturnedVal, if you run more than once.

Answer (score 1):

Try some easy:

```
DECLARE @i float --If your function returns float...
SELECT @i = dbo.UDF_CONVERSION (7.68,1,null,null,25,5)  

--DEBUG (remove PRINT comment)
--PRINT @i
```

If you need CONVERT a value inside sp_executesql

```
DECLARE @A nVARCHAR(1000),@i float
DECLARE @ParmDefinition nvarchar(500);

SET @A=  dbo.UDF_CONVERSION (7.68,1,null,null,25,5)  
SET @A = N'SELECT @retvalOUT = CONVERT(float, '''+ @A +''')'
SET @ParmDefinition = N'@retvalOUT float OUTPUT';

EXEC sp_executesql @A, @ParmDefinition, @retvalOUT = @i OUTPUT;

SELECT  @i
```

Comment: +1 exactly - if the function returns **float** - store it in a **float** variable ... and you can even print this result out - no problem..

Comment: actually the function returns (7.68/1000.00)/1.0026  need sme query to convert this to a float value

Comment: Ok. First, sp_executesql always returns 0 (success) or 1 (failure). You need use params for gets a Result Sets. Read more here: msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933299(v=sql.80).aspx. Update my answer.